# on hovers with parents and child in css

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a situation in which i want to change the color of my box with the on hover from the container i which this box is found.

I found out how to do this through a different question here on stackoverflow [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

But now i want to change the color of my box to a third option when i hover the box itself.

This is and exaple html with css.

```
<body>

<div class="container">container
<div class="box">
box</div>

</div

</body>
</html>
```

and the css.

```
.container{
background-color:grey;
height: 100px;
width:100px;
}
.container:hover .box{
background-color: aqua;
}
.box{
background-color: blue;
    width:50px;
height: 50px;
}
.box:hover{
background-color: white;
}
```

This is the way i tried to do it but this does not work. The first steps works but i can't get the third color.

Comment: Your div is missing a `>`, correct your code and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
.box:hover{
   background-color: white
}
```

TO

```
.container:hover>.box:hover{
   background-color: white
}
```

And try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/czmzxd6j/

Comment: Why use 2 times hover? it doens make any sense

Comment: SImply because he asked for: But now i want to change the color of my box to a third option when i hover the box itself....  
   Please read in details before voting down.

Comment: @Rickert it's more specific, I've explained it all in my own answer for you. because you can hover over a parent and child at the same time. it's kinda how inheritance works

Comment: @Enzo but when you hover the child you automaticly hove the parent so it looks useless to me

Comment: @Rickert if you don't add the hover as I did, then the box will only have 2 background colors and not 3 as tjapko asked for.
The Aqua background on HOVER will be ignored. Here is jsfiddle with css you suggest: http://jsfiddle.net/czmzxd6j/1/

Comment: I still think that 2 :hovers are useless

Comment: Thank you! 
for the awnser and the site! :)

Comment: @Rickert it is not for me because im using this in a situation with buttons and i want to change an image slightly depending on where the mouse is. the example was an easier was to explain what i wanted to do though :)

Comment: @tjapko if my answers resolves your problem, please select it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a more specific selector.

You're setting `.container:hover .box {...}` which is more specific than `.box:hover`.

Your issue will be resolved if you use `.container:hover .box:hover {...}` because this is *more specific* than the one with just the `.box` at the end.

Using the *direct-child* selector isn't the way nor is `!important` (sorry guys, no offence but it's just not the correct approach here.)

CSS is all about overwriting and that is why these things can be nasty sometimes.

Whenever something doesn't get applied correctly just think to yourself for 3 seconds: "Are there any other **selectors** that manipulate this element that could be more specific?".

With the general selector `.box:hover` **any** box anywhere in the DOM will have that hover as long as it has the `.box` class *however* this is not true for the other selector including `.container:hover .box:hover`.

That selector is actually **more** specific due to the fact that now only `.box` elements *within* the `.container` elements get the hover.

By specifying the general selector instead of one that is **atleast** as specific it will simply be overwritten by the more specific one, that's why you need to re-add `.container:hover` to the selector.

I hope it makes sense to you.

Good luck!

Comment: @tjapko if it worked for you, to the left of my answer are a tick and optionally an upvote if you check the tick it means your question is solved - other people who come here in the future can get something useful out of the information provided :)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
.box:hover{
background-color: white !important;
}
```

you can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/fusg2o3f/

Comment: its better dont use important